# Get a list of stack dependencies using CDK cli

Tags: aws-cdk

Is it somehow possible to get a list of the stacks that another stack depends on using the AWS CDK CLI? For example, given a list of stacks that looks something like:

```js
const app = new App();
const alphaStack = new Stack(app);

const betaStack = new Stack(app);
betaStack.addDependency(alphaStack);

const gammaStack = new Stack(app);
gammaStack.addDependency(gammaStack);

const deltaStack = new Stack(app);
deltaStack.addDependency(betaStack);
deltaStack.addDependency(gammaStack);
```

I'd like to run a command that could give me output similar to the following:

```
$ cdk list-deps alpha-stack  # no result

$ cdk list-deps beta-stack
alpha-stack

$ cdk list-deps gamma-stack
alpha-stack

$ cdk list-deps delta-stack
beta-stack
gamma-stack
```

Specifically, I'd like to be able to run this *before* I deploy my stacks.

Comment: Do you mean nested stacks? If so, you could possibly write a script that uses the `ParentId` field returned by `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` and then trace back the parents.

Comment: No, not nested stacks. CDK stacks that depend on each other (eg. explicitly or implicitly due to outputs). I've updated the example to try and better reflect what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this helps anyone in the future; the following seems to solve the problem that I wanted to solve:

```js
// the stack that we're interested in finding deps for
const stackName = "...";

// assuming app is as defined in the question
const { stacks } = app.synth();

stacks
  .find(({ stackName }) => stackName === searchForStackName)
  ?.dependencies.forEach((dep) => console.log(dep.id));
```

Caveats:

- It's obviously not built-in to the CLI, and requires exposing `app` from your CDK definitions.
- This does require calling `synth` on the app. Initially my understanding was that this creates some artifacts within AWS, which I wanted to avoid; but it seems that's not actually the case.
- I'm not sure how reliable/stable `dep.id` is from this snippet/answer. Although it has so far been robust enough for my purposes, `dependencies` returns a list of `CloudArtifact` which I'm not certain if it will always represent a `Stack`.

Answer (score 6):

Run `cdk synth STACK_NAME`

and you should find the dependencies from `cdk.out/manifest.json`

```
❯ jq '.artifacts.STACK_NAME.dependencies' cdk.out/manifest.json
[
  "STACK_NAME.assets"
  ...
]
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer.  (jq command is used not only for reading JSON data but also to display data by removing the particular key. The following command will print all key values of ...)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't quite as robust as what you're looking for but here is a useful command to find the stacks that depend on a particular export:

```
aws cloudformation list-imports --export-name EXPORT_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to do this before anything is deployed, so the stack isn't yet in cloudformation. I've updated the question to clarify

Answer (score -1):

You can also run

`cdk destroy stackName`

It will ask you for confirmation of the dependencies necesary to destroy your stack.

This is a dangerous operation and should be done with care because it can destroy your stacks.